# How to project map & reduce in ProjectionOperation in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I can not able to do `map` and `reduce` operation in java mongodb in ProjectionOperation.

I have project operation in native `mongo query` like this:

```
{
    $project: {
        data: {
            $map: {
                input: params.timeArray,
                in: {
                    "key": "$$this",
                    "value": { "$cond": [{ "$in": ["$$this", "$data.date"] }, "$data", []] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I also want to do `reduce` operation in another projection operation like this:

```
{
    $project: {
        id: 1,
        data: { $reduce: { input: "$data", initialValue: [], in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] } } }
    }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation1 = Aggregation.project()
                .and(VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("data"/*here, I want to pass timeArray*/)
                        .as("input")
                        .andApply(context -> new BasicDBObject("value",
                                ConditionalOperators.when(where("$$this").in("$data.date"))
                                        .then("$data")
                                        .otherwise(new HashSet<>()))))
                .as("data");
```

But it didn't give me desired result.

I'm using `springboot` version 1.5.10.RELEASE

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try writing the query as it is in your `Repository` using `@Query` annotation?

Comment: Please tell what the field `data` looks like; post a sample value.

Comment: ["2020-02-20","2020-02-21","2020-02-22",...]  or 
["2020-01","2020-02","2020-03",...]  or 
["2018","2019","2020",...]
(ArrayList of String).

Comment: You are using a `$data.date`, that is the array I think).

Comment: Its not clear what you are saying. Your aggregation shows that the field `date` within the object `data` is an array (see my earlier comment). Hence the reference, "$data.date" in the `$map`'s  code `{ "$in": [ "$$this", "$data.date" ] }`. Please confirm.

Comment: before $project my result looks like this format.
{
    "_id" : "2020-03-02",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2020-03-02",
            "key1":"val1"
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2020-03-02",
            "key1":"val"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : "2020-03-05",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2020-03-05",
            "key1":"value"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

The projection operation code run using Spring `MongoTemplate` API:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");

String [] TIME_ARRAY = { "2020-02-20", "2020-02-21", "2020-02-22" }; // values from params.timeArray

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
  project("_id", "data")
    .andArrayOf(TIME_ARRAY).as("timeArray")
    .andArrayOf().as("emptyArray"),
  project() 
    .and(
        Map.itemsOf("timeArray")
            .as("element")
            .andApply(ctx -> 
                new Document("key", "$$element")
                    .append("value", 
                        new Document("$cond", 
                            Arrays.asList( 
                                new Document("$in", 
                                    Arrays.asList("$$element", "$data.date")), 
                                       "$data", 
                                       "$emptyArray")
                        )
                    ) 
                )
            )
        .as("data")
);

AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "collection", Document.class);

results.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. It shows an error like these : 

" Cannot resolve method 'newAggregation(?, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation)' "

and

" Cannot resolve method 'andArrayOf' in 'ProjectionOperation' ".

Comment: Its a compilation error. Are you using an IDE? If so you will be able to correct it easily (the IDE will be able to guide you). The code I had posted compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Link to [andArrayOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770748/how-to-project-map-reduce-in-projectionoperation-in-spring-data-mongodb/60773442?noredirect=1#comment107586080_60773442)

Comment: It shows project does not have method "andArrayOf".

Comment: Here is the link to it (the previous one was linked wrongly!): [andArrayOf](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ProjectionOperation.html#andArrayOf-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: `andArrayOf` is a method of `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation` class.

Comment: I can not found this method in ProjectionOperation class in springboot version 1.5.10.RELEASE.

Comment: Can you click the link to `andArrayOf` from my previous comment and see in what class the method is defined in? May be it is the different **version** of the Spring APIs you are looking at. **NOTE:** `andArrayOf` was introduced in version 2.2.

Comment: The code I had posted is based upon the **Spring Data MongoDB version 2.2.6** APIs.